# How can I color every output on a linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, colors, command

I often use a colorizer "ccze" which is pretty cool, - it colors text on my shell. I just pipe any output through it.

```
cat /etc/nginx.nginx.conf | ccze -A
```

How can I do this with *all* commands by default?

Comment: *Every* command? Even `vi`/`emacs`, `elinks`/`w3m`, shells?

Comment: ok. certainly not to every command, maybe the better question would be : How to add it to _some_ commands?

Answer (score 0):

That usually depends on the font of your terminal emulator program yourself. In the settings, you can modify the type/color of your terminal font. As far as coloration though, see if the ccze package is able to be called every time you concatenate a text file via your .bash_profile (.bashrc if it's a non-login shell).

Answer (score 0):

I would hesitate to do this, but in your shell (I assume bash) you can redirect all stdout like this:

```
exec 1> >(ccze -A)
```